# How do I cancel the effect of "ESC-F" in "less" without canceling the running process?

Tags: command-line, less

When I use `less`, at times I like to have things go on for a while so I use the <kbd>ESC-F</kbd> sequence key which, up to here, does what I want.

The only way I've found to go back to the normal `less` command is to use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. However, when I do that, it stops (Cancels) the running process.

What I'm looking for is a way to return to the normal `less` functionality without stopping the running process so I can look at a few things, then see the following output without having to restart my process.

Is there such a capability?

Comment: Is this when you use `less` as part of a pipeline, as in `some_command | less`?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of `less`:

```
       F      Scroll  forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is
              reached.  Normally this command would be used  when  already  at
              the  end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a file
              which is growing while it is being  viewed.   (The  behavior  is
              similar to the "tail -f" command.)

       ESC-F  Like  F,  but  as soon as a line is found which matches the last
              search pattern, the terminal bell is rung and forward  scrolling
              stops.
```

If your list of standard options for `less` (usually specified in `$LESS` environment variable or in the `~/.lesskey` file, but possibly also defined by shell aliases or similar) includes `-K`, it will be impossible to stop `less`'s <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Esc-F</kbd> functions without exiting `less`:

```
       -K or --quit-on-intr
              Causes less to exit immediately (with status 2) when  an  inter‐
              rupt  character  (usually  ^C) is typed.  Normally, an interrupt
              character causes less to stop whatever it is doing and return to
              its  command  prompt.  Note that use of this option makes it im‐
              possible to return to the command prompt from the "F" command.
```

Because <kbd>Esc-F</kbd> is a variant of the <kbd>F</kbd> function, I'd expect the `-K` option to have the same effect on it too.

Comment: So... what you're saying is I can use `Ctrl-C` if I don't use `-K`. That I've gotten already and it works. The problem is that it stops the process passing the data to less. What I was hoping is a way to turn on the scrolling and then stopping the scrolling at some point, but not stop the process passing (generating) the data.